# First Powershell Function and Regex to verify user input

Tags: function, powershell, user-input

I am not having any luck trying to get my first function to work. I need to test three strings to see if the the string is empty, or if any non allowed characters are present. If there is a invalid string, set $Errorstate to 2. and amended a string with a new line of text. If no error is present exit the function. As It stands right now the code accepts all input and passes It through.

```
#Error Function
Function Test-isGood($Vaule,$Errtxt,$Msg,$State){
   if($Vaule -eq ""){
        $Msg = $Msg + "`n" + "Please Fill in the"+ "$Errtxt" + "Box"
        $State = 2
    }
    if ($Vaule -match "\A[^a-z0-9 _&-]+\Z") {
        $State = $State
    }else{
        $Msg = $Msg + "`n" + "Please Use A-Z, a-z and 0-9 in the"+"$Errtxt" +"Box"
        $State = 2
    }
    $Errorstate = $state
    $ErrorMessage = $Msg

}

#Name Holders
$Temp1 = "S0#"
$Temp2 = "Job Name"
$Temp3 = "Contractor"

#Call Error Function
Test-isGood $TextBox1.Text $Temp1 $ErrorMessage $Errorstate
Test-isGood $TextBox2.Text $Temp2 $ErrorMessage $Errorstate
Test-isGood $TextBox3.Text $Temp3 $ErrorMessage $Errorstate
```

Thanks for you help,
gizmobrat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are appending text to the variable `$Msg`, which only exists within the function.
One way of achieving what you want is by using [Scoping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6) the variables the function needs to append to.
This also removes the need for two of the parameters:

```
# Error Function
Function Test-IsGood([string]$Value, [string]$TextBox){
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Value)) {
        $Script:ErrorMessage += "`r`nPlease Fill in the '$TextBox' Box"
        $Script:Errorstate = 2
    }
    if ($Value -match "[^a-z0-9 _&-]") {
        $Script:ErrorMessage += "`r`nPlease Use A-Z, a-z and 0-9 in the '$TextBox' Box"
        $Script:Errorstate = 2
    }
}

# Name Holders
$TextBoxName1 = "S0#"
$TextBoxName2 = "Job Name"
$TextBoxName3 = "Contractor"

# initialize the variables (here using script scope)
$Script:ErrorMessage = ''
$Script:Errorstate   = 0

#Call Error Function
Test-isGood '' $TextBoxName1
Test-isGood '&*' $TextBoxName2
Test-isGood '@@@' $TextBoxName3

# show the message and state
$ErrorMessage
$Errorstate
```

Result:

> ```
> Please Fill in the 'S0#' Box
> Please Use A-Z, a-z and 0-9 in the 'Job Name' Box
> Please Use A-Z, a-z and 0-9 in the 'Contractor' Box
> 2
> ```

<sup>I've changed some of the variable names to be more self-explanatory. Also, on Windows systems, the NewLine is made up of two characters "`r`n" (CRLF)</sup>